# Send message to .NET app from javascript?

Tags: .net, javascript

I'm working on a help system in HTML, and I'd like to have links that the user can click to execute commands inside an application written in .NET (eg, to complete steps in a tutorial or workflow).  I've looked at the TCard() method for HTML help, but it only works in compiled help (.chm), and I'd like to do this in plain html that can be viewed from browsers other than IE.

Is this possible?  If so, what would be the simplest/best way to do this?

Comment: Are you planning/hoping to support Mono, or is a Windows-only solution OK with you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this on Windows only, you might want to take a look at a [custom application protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx). The page could link to "myhelp3000:LoadStage(2)" and your app could do something special in response.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will look at that.  Ideally, this solution would work on Windows and OSX.  But we may have to live with Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use asp.net ajax web services. Here's a tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/tutorials/ASPNETAJAXWebServicesTutorials.aspx